# How to render specific data from firebase and Ionic 3

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I am working on an Ionic 3 project and has firebase database. I am able to retrieve all data from table and user for to display them in HTML. But got no luck in displaying data for specific id and also with  where condition.

These query are the php mysqli query as a reference
query = SELECT * FROM users  - working great

query1 = SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 'some id'    - not working

query2 = SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 1        - not working

Here is my user provider

I have created a render Users function to retreive all user data,

```
renderUsers(): Observable<any> {

    return new Observable(observer => {
      let users: any = [];
      firebase.database().ref('users').orderByKey().once('value', (items: any) => {
        items.forEach((item) => {
          users.push({
            id: item.key,
            email: item.val().email,
            password: item.val().password,
            image: item.val().image,
          });
        });

        observer.next(users);
        observer.complete();
      },
        (error) => {
          console.log("Observer error: ", error);
          console.dir(error);
          observer.error(error)
        });

    });
  }
```

my profile.ts

```
  loadAndParseUser() {
      this.user = this._DBUSER.renderUsers();
      console.log(this.user);
      this._LOADER.hidePreloader();
    }
```

profile.html

```
<ion-col col-12  *ngFor="let u of user | async">
          <h5>{{u.email}}</h5>
```

Comment: What code have you tried to perform your queries? Does it give you any errors or unexpected results? Did you check out [the docs about filtering data in firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data)?

Comment: I am using ionic framework and Firebase. Basically html, sass, angular,typescript...

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure why you mySQL queries are involved in any of this. But I assume you are using it as a way to express what you actually want. Therefore it's also safe to assume you're pretty used to a relational database where you query data like that. But in firebase, it works out differently.

I'm unsure how you exactly structured the database, but let's assume you have a structure that looks like this.

```
 users
   e96a-4f66-b3d5-9c4c484316c1
     name: metalhead101
     score: 45
     status: 3
   a79c-4839-be70-6d683f3f4c50
     name: realappie
     score: 1226
     status: 2
```

Where `fkaljf92kfja` and `fafau292afjf` are your user identifiers. Or in the case of firebase, those will be your users unique ids which you will capture in the account creation or federated identity provider sign in callback. See [managing users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) for more information on that.

To perform the equivalent of `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 'some id'` you would do it like this.

`firebase.database().ref('users/' + id)`

Now we have the simple part out of the way, let's get to your second query.

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 1`

For you to be able to filter on a certain field, you need to denormalize your data. This [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) by the firebase team does a great job explaining this. But the crux of it is that we want to optimize our database for read operations at the cost of more writing. So instead of storing the status under a `user` node. We will store it under a `statuses` node instead. So our previous structure ends up looking like this

```
 users
   e96a-4f66-b3d5-9c4c484316c1
     name: metalhead101
     score: 45

   a79c-4839-be70-6d683f3f4c50
     name: realappie
     score: 1226

statuses
    2
        users: 
            :randomId
                a79c-4839-be70-6d683f3f4c50 // userId
    3
        users: 
            :randomId
                e96a-4f66-b3d5-9c4c484316c1 // userId
```

Which will allow you to easily query on status values like so

`firebase.database().ref('statuses/' + 1)`

Which would return you an object with all the users with that status. You can then fetch those users separately.

**EDIT:** I think @PeterHaddad's solution to the second problem is less complex, although my explanation of denormalization could be helpful to keep your database reads fast in the future.

Also please consider using [angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) instead of creating your own observables. It will make your life much easier as integrates rxjs on top of the firebase sdk.

Comment: thnx , I will give it a try

Comment: a79c-4839-be70-6d683f3f4c50 & e96a-4f66-b3d5-9c4c484316c1 are my identifiers according to your example. I am using key of firebase database as an identifier. Will that be an issue.. Plz help/ THanKs.

Comment: I am curious how you are adding users to the database. something along the lines of `database.ref('users').push()` will get the job done. But then you are using firebase generated ids for your user identifiers, which makes it hard to do things like, editing the current user. Firebase authenticated users have uid, therefor I suggested you to use those user identifiers as database id.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
public userData; // define as public variable.  
firebase
.database()
.ref(`person1/${id}`)
.on("value", (user) => {
    userData = user.val();
});
```

in html like this

```
 name : {{ userData.name }}<br>
    address : {{ {{ userData.name }}<br>
    ....other like this
```

Comment: I am planning to implement something like this                                               const personRef: firebase.database.Reference = firebase.database().ref(`/person1/` + id);
  personRef.on('value', personSnapshot => {
    myPerson = personSnapshot.val();
  });

Comment: user.ts
  renderUserByKey(id) {
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`users/${id}`)
    .on("value", (users) => {
      console.log(users.val());
    });
}

Comment: profile.ts  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.userId = '-L8cNz1aN5b0OgNPddRO;'
    this._LOADER.displayPreloader();
    this.platform.ready()
      .then(() => {
        // firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.pass)
        //   .then((credentials) => {
            this.loadAndParseUser(this.userId);
          // })
          // .catch((err: Error) => {
          //   console.log(err.message);
          // });
      });
  }


loadAndParseUser(id) {
  this.user = this._DBUSER.renderUserByKey(id);
  console.log(this.user);
  this._LOADER.hidePreloader();
}

Comment: one thing to remember.. I have made mine own custom table in firebase database with name users. Will that be an issue. ????

Comment: Now I getting this out put {address: "Janpath", country: "Biratnagar", email: "Aasen@gmail.com", gender: "Male", homeno: "562516", …}
address
:
"Janpath"
country
:
"Biratnagar"
email
:
"Aasen@gmail.com"
gender
:
"Male"
homeno
:
"562516"
image
:
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/housemealz.appspot.com/o/users%2Fuser-1522169803089.jpg?alt=media&token=579b59c1-52f9-4497-8d76-58ed80c07420"
mobileno
:
"976162738"
name
:
"Aaden sah"
password
:
"admin"
payType
:
"Weekly"
role
:
"chef"

Comment: now how to show this in my html view please help..tnx

Answer (score 1):

To be able to do those two queries:

query1:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 'some id' - not working
```

query2:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 1 - not working
```

you need to use:

```
orderByChild("id").equalTo(idhere);
```

and

```
ordreByChild("status").equalTo("1");
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data

Comment: thnx for response, can you please share me an html, ts example with code. I am bit confused reading the document about how to get the data and display in html. Thnx

Comment: You can't do that since there is no "and" clause in firebase real-time database @Raj